# Reconciling two notions of equivariant isotopy

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Here is one definition of $G$-isotopy:

Let $N$ and $M$ be two $G$-manifolds. A $G$-isotopy is a (smooth) map $H : N \times [0,1] \to M$ so that at all times $t$, the map $H_t$ is a $G$-equivariant embedding.

This definition appears in several places. For instance, it is in
*Abe, Kojun*, [**On the equivariant isotopy classes of some equivariant imbeddings of spheres**](https://doi.org/10.2977/prims/1195188832), Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci., Kyoto Univ. 14, 655-672 (1978). [ZBL0405.57024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0405.57024).

Here is another:
Let $M$ be a $G$-manifold and $N$ a $G$-invariant submanifold. An equivariant isotopy of $N$ is an isotopy $H : N \times [0,1] \to M$ so that at all times $t$, the image of the embedding $H_t$ is $G$-invariant.

This definition does not quite appear in *Freedman, Michael H.; Luo, Feng*, [**Equivariant isotopy of unknots to round circles**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641(94)00086-I), Topology Appl. 64, No. 1, 59-74 (1995). [ZBL0830.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0830.53002)., but the main theorem of that paper is about producing isotopies with $G$-invariant images, and the paper has "equivariant isotopy" in the title.

(I remark that this paper is really only interested in finite groups, and one can show that the isotopies produced are equivalent to $G$-isotopies in the first sense).

---

The substantial difference between the definitions is that in the first, the $G$-action on $N$ is fixed while in the second, it can vary.

For example, if $G=\mathbb Z$, we may allows $G$ to act on $\mathbb R^2$ by $n \cdot (x,y) = (x+ny, y)$. Let $G$ act on $\mathbb R$ by $n\cdot x = x+n$. The function $H: \mathbb R \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $H(x,t) = (x, 1-t)$ is what I called an 'equivariant isotopy' above, but there is no $G$-isotopy from $H_0$ that even has the same image as $H_1$, since the $G$ action on $H_0$ is nontrivial but on $H_1$ it is trivial.

That is, even if we care mainly about the images at various times $t$ of isotopy maps, and not necessarily the specific embeddings, the two notions of $G$- and equivariant-isotopy diverge.

---

The example I gave concerned noncompact manifolds. One can easily adjust the example to be about compact manifolds. It also concerned the noncompact group $\mathbb{Z}$. I suspect, but do not know, that it is known that the two notions of isotopy are much more similar when $G$ is assumed to be compact (or perhaps specifically when $G$ is finite). Is there somewhere I can learn more about this?